# How to implement Fail2Ban inside a Docker container running Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik, nginx-ingress, fail2ban

I am trying to implement [fail2ban](https://github.com/crazy-max/docker-fail2ban/blob/master/examples/compose/docker-compose.yml) inside my docker environment that uses my Nginx logs. <-- I may in the future just target the entire `traefik` logs.

```
version: '3'
services:
  fail2ban:
    image: 'crazymax/fail2ban:latest'
    restart: 'always'
    network_mode: 'host'
    cap_add:
      - 'NET_ADMIN'
      - 'NET_RAW'
    volumes:
      - 'nginx-log:/var/log:ro'
      - 'fail2ban-data:/data'
    env_file:
      - './fail2ban.env'
  laravel-mysql:
    [SNIP]
  laravel-php:
    [SNIP]
  laravel-nginx:
    image: 'nginx:alpine'
    restart: 'always'
    depends_on:
      - 'laravel-php'
    expose:
      - '80'
    volumes:
      - 'laravel-src:/var/www/html'
      - './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
      - 'nginx-log:/var/log/nginx'
    networks:
      - 'traefik'
      - 'laravel'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=traefik'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=http'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN}`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx.middlewares=redirect@file'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN}`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx-https.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx-https.tls.certresolver=${DNS_PROVIDER}'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx-https.tls.domains[0].main=${DOMAIN}'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx-https.tls.domains[1].main=www.${DOMAIN}'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx.service=nginx'
      - 'traefik.http.services.nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=80'
      - 'traefik.http.services.nginx.loadBalancer.passHostHeader=true'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.nginx.middlewares=https-redirect'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{any:.+}`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.entrypoints=http'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.middlewares=https_redirect'
networks:
  laravel:
    driver: 'bridge'
  traefik:
    name: '${TRAEFIK_NETWORK}'
    external: 'true'
volumes:
  laravel-database:
    driver: 'local'
  laravel-src:
    driver: 'local'
  nginx-log:
    driver: 'local'
  fail2ban-data:
    driver: 'local'
```

Running `docker logs laravel_fail2ban_1 --tail 100` after `docker-compose up -d` shows me:

```
Setting timezone to Europe/London...
Setting SSMTP configuration...
WARNING: SSMTP_HOST must be defined if you want fail2ban to send emails
Initializing files and folders...
Setting Fail2ban configuration...
Checking for custom actions in /data/action.d...
Checking for custom filters in /data/filter.d...
2021-08-01 11:40:13,199 fail2ban.configreader   [1]: INFO    Loading configs for fail2ban under /etc/fail2ban
2021-08-01 11:40:13,202 fail2ban.configparserinc[1]: INFO      Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf']
2021-08-01 11:40:13,203 fail2ban.configparserinc[1]: INFO      Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf']
2021-08-01 11:40:13,204 fail2ban                [1]: INFO    Using socket file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
2021-08-01 11:40:13,204 fail2ban                [1]: INFO    Using pid file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid, [INFO] logging to STDOUT
2021-08-01 11:40:13,218 fail2ban.configreader   [1]: INFO    Loading configs for jail under /etc/fail2ban
2021-08-01 11:40:13,219 fail2ban.configparserinc[1]: INFO      Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf']
2021-08-01 11:40:13,255 fail2ban.configparserinc[1]: INFO      Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/paths-debian.conf']
2021-08-01 11:40:13,257 fail2ban.configparserinc[1]: INFO      Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/paths-common.conf']
2021-08-01 11:40:13,260 fail2ban.configparserinc[1]: INFO      Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/paths-overrides.local']
2021-08-01 11:40:13,263 fail2ban.configparserinc[1]: INFO      Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/paths-common.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/paths-debian.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf']
2021-08-01 11:40:13,369 fail2ban.server         [1]: INFO    --------------------------------------------------
2021-08-01 11:40:13,372 fail2ban.server         [1]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.11.2
2021-08-01 11:40:13,373 fail2ban.observer       [1]: INFO    Observer start...
2021-08-01 11:40:13,382 fail2ban.database       [1]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/data/db/fail2ban.sqlite3'
2021-08-01 11:40:13,385 fail2ban.database       [1]: WARNING New database created. Version '4'
Server ready
```

If I now attempt to stress my application, no logs are populated in fail2ban but if I `--follow` my nginx container logs, I see the requests firing away.

If I `docker exec -it -u root laravel_fail2ban_1 /bin/bash -c 'ls -la /var/log'` I can see my logs in the correct location:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Aug  1 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Dec 16  2020 ..
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 Jul  6 20:40 access.log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 Jul  6 20:40 error.log -> /dev/stderr
```

I see the issue may be when I try `cat /var/log/access.log`. It is symlinked to the `/dev/stdout` which means the terminal tries attaching to it. I cannot unlink it whilst running:

```
docker exec -it -u root laravel_fail2ban_1 /bin/bash -c 'unlink /var/log/access.log'
unlink: can't remove file '/var/log/access.log': Read-only file system
```

Any help appreciated to get this working. I need to keep the symlink on the volume so I can use docker logs on my nginx container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/var/log/access.log` is a symlink to stdout, it's not going to be available in the other container: `/dev/stdout` points to the stdout *of the current process*, so when `fail2ban` attempts to read from it, it gets its own stdout, rather than the stdout of the nginx process.

If you want `fail2ban` to be able to read the logs from nginx, you will need to write them to an actual file. If you *also* want them showing up on the container stdout, you can run something like a `tail -f` in the background of the nginx container.

Comment: I take it this action needs to be done outside the container then? Thanks for the explanation, I guessed it would be an issue with the Stdout because when I tried to cat it, it showed nothing and attached to the process

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't need to be done outside the container. I was describing how you would solve it *inside* a container: write nginx logs to a file inside the nginx container, mount the log directory inside the fail2ban container, etc.

Comment: I see, I could do this in the nginx config right? The  as you say, tail f it for the output. Or do I need to do this another way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60429415/5897602 Something like this perhaps?

Comment: This worked. Removing the symlink now allows me to cat the access log inside the fail2ban container in the `/var/log` directory. No mention of the STDOUT logs of the fail2ban container of the log being used --> how can I verify this is now working do you know?

Comment: I guess do something that would trigger your `fail2ban` rules and see if it works? I'm not fall that familiar with the `fail2ban` side of things.

Comment: I managed to fix this doing what you said. ```unlink "`docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' laravel_nginx-log`/access.log" && docker-compose up -d --force-recreate``` and then I just added a cmd for `tail -f` in the nginx container inside the `docker-compose.yml`.